# Merge pdfs and add bookmark with iText in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, bookmarks

**How do I add bookmarks to an existing PDFs by using iText?**

I am merging multiple PDFs together into one PDF and I need to build bookmarks for the final PDF.  For example, I have three PDFs: doc1.pdf, doc2.pdf and doc3.pdf, doc1 and doc2 belong to Group1, doc3 belongs to Group2. I need to merge them and have to build nested bookmarks for the resulting PDFs like so:

```
Group1 
   doc1  
   doc2  
Group2 
   doc3
```

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a [MergeWithOutlines](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/MergeWithOutlines) example that concatenates three existing PDFs using `PdfCopy` (I assume that you already know that part).

While doing so, I create an `outlines` object like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> outlines = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
```

and I add elements to this `outlines` object:

```
HashMap<String, Object> helloworld = new HashMap<String, Object>();
helloworld.put("Title", "Hello World");
helloworld.put("Action", "GoTo");
helloworld.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", page));
outlines.add(helloworld);
```

When I want some hierachy, I introduce `kids`:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> kids = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> link1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
link1.put("Title", "link1");
link1.put("Action", "GoTo");
link1.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", page));
kids.add(link1);
helloworld.put("Kids", kids);
```

If you want an entry without a link, remove the lines that put an `Action` and a `Page`.

Once you're finished, add the outlines to the copy object:

```
copy.setOutlines(outlines);
```

Look at the [resulting PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/merge_with_outlines.pdf) and you'll see the outlines in the bookmarks panel.

Comment: Bruno, if you have a lot of pdf files that you are concatenating like this, is there something similar to pdfWriter.freeReader() that can reduce the memory footprint?