# How to Add bookmarks to PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i have 4 pdf templates files by using itextsharp i added values and i merged/added 4 pdf files into single document, so all 4 pages are under one single pdf file name.Now i want to add bookmark to my pdf file. is there any way to do in C# ?for better understanding ,please refer below images
[image: My pdf looks like this image 1]
[image: I want to display like image 2]

Hi ,this is what i am trying to do, i am not getting any error but still there is no bookmark in my pdf, i want to add bookmark with 4 sections as showed in the image.after merging i want add bookmark to final pdf.

```
enter code herepublic string MergePDFs()
    {
        string outPutFilePath = @"D:\jeldsbre.pdf";
        string genereatedpdfs = @"D:\genereatedpdfs";

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outPutFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdf.SetMergeFields();
            pdfDoc.Open();
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(genereatedpdfs);
            Console.WriteLine("Merging files count: " + files.Length);
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ". Adding: " + file);
                pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(file));

                i++;
            }
          List<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            IList<Dictionary<string, object>> tempBookmarks =  new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            SimpleBookmark.ShiftPageNumbers(tempBookmarks, 1, null);
            bookmarks.AddRange(tempBookmarks);
            SimpleBookmark.ShiftPageNumbers(tempBookmarks, 3, null);
           bookmarks.AddRange(tempBookmarks);
           pdf.Outlines = bookmarks;
           if (pdfDoc != null)
                pdfDoc.Close();
            string base64 = GetBase64(outPutFilePath);
            return base64;
        }               

    }
```

Comment: This question sounds like possible duplicate of [Merge pdfs and add bookmark with iText in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688308/merge-pdfs-and-add-bookmark-with-itext-in-java) with the only difference that this question is about iTextSharp / C# (but the answer is almost identical as there is hardly a difference between iText and iTextSharp)

Comment: Thanks...i will follow this and i will update you.

Comment: I've also provided the "full-blown" answer (Java and C#), but that answer assumes that the existing documents already have bookmarks. (It's not clear from your question if this is the case.)

Comment: hi @BrunoLowagie please see my code and give your comments

Comment: i am able to merge , but i am not able to add bookmarks

Comment: If you want me to comment on your code right now, you won't like what I'll say. To avoid this, please throw away your code. Go for a walk. As soon as you have cleared your head, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688308/merge-pdfs-and-add-bookmark-with-itext-in-java and start anew.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your original PDFs already have bookmarks, then you should concatenate not only the documents (using the `PdfCopy` class), you should also concatenate the different bookmarks structures of the different files (using the `SimpleBookMark` class), not forgetting to take into account that you need to shift the page numbers correctly.

This is done in the [ConcatenateBookmarks](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141) example in chapter 7 of my book:

```
// Create a list for the bookmarks
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> bookmarks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
List<HashMap<String, Object>> tmp;
for (int i  = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    reader = new PdfReader(src[i]);
    // merge the bookmarks
    tmp = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
    SimpleBookmark.shiftPageNumbers(tmp, page_offset, null);
    bookmarks.addAll(tmp);
    // add the pages
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    page_offset += n;
    for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
// Add the merged bookmarks
copy.setOutlines(bookmarks);
```

For a C# version of this example, please take a look at http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C07 for the corresponding iTextSharp example:

```
// Create a list for the bookmarks
List<Dictionary<String, Object>> bookmarks = 
    new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();            
for (int i  = 0; i < src.Count; i++) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src[i]);
    // merge the bookmarks
    IList<Dictionary<String, Object>> tmp = 
    SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
    SimpleBookmark.ShiftPageNumbers(tmp, page_offset, null);
    foreach (var d in tmp) bookmarks.Add(d);
    // add the pages
    int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
    page_offset += n;
    for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
}
// Add the merged bookmarks
copy.Outlines = bookmarks;
```

If the existing documents don't have any bookmarks (or if you don't want to copy any existing documents), then your question is a duplicate of a question I answered half a year ago: [Merge pdfs and add bookmark with iText in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688308/merge-pdfs-and-add-bookmark-with-itext-in-java)