# how to pass top value in addBookmark function of PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am adding Bookmarks to new created PDF but on click on bookmark it goes to page top, not at current line of original PDF.

I am getting following details of bookmark:

```
OrderedDict([(0.0, {'/Top': 750, 'name': u'SIDDHARTHA', 'page_no': 3, 'children': OrderedDict()}), (1.0, {'/Top': 750, 'name': u'Chapter 01', 'page_no': 5, 'children': OrderedDict([(2.0, {'/Top': 590, 'name': u'Nested 1', 'page_no': 6, 'children': OrderedDict([(2.0, {'/Top': 518, 'name': u'Nested 2', 'page_no': 6, 'children': OrderedDict([(2.0, {'/Top': 390, 'name': u'Nested 4', 'page_no': 6, 'children': OrderedDict([(2.0, {'/Top': 326, 'name': u'Nested 5', 'page_no': 6, 'children': OrderedDict()})])})])})])})])})
```

I am getting bookmark from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197544/how-to-get-bookmark-of-pdf-and-add-bookmark-to-new-pdf).

I want to pass `/FitH` and `Top` value to

```
obj.addBookmark(namelevel, bookmarkdict[pagekeylevel]["page_no"]-first_page_no, levelparent)
```

I refer following links, but I am able to use these values:

1. [link1](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.addBookmark)
2. [link2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.addLink)