# Build PDF bookmarks while merging PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, bookmarks

I'm merging PDF's through a loop using iTextSharp. In that same loop I created the bookmarks that are supposed to have 3 levels (chapter, section, subsection). The 3 level structure is displayed correctly for each entry, but is not grouped among pages belonging to the same chapter, section or subsection.

How is it done? 
Regards, Martin

```
private void MergePDFs()
{
    DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
    DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(args);

    DataTable table = view.ToTable();
    List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();

    foreach (DataRow myRow in table.Rows)
    {

        PdfReader Reader = new PdfReader(Convert.ToString(myRow[0]));

        Chapter Chapter = new Chapter(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(myRow[1])), 0);
        Chapter.NumberDepth = 0;
        Section Section = Chapter.AddSection(Convert.ToString(myRow[10]), 0);
        Section.NumberDepth = 0;
        Section SubSection = Section.AddSection(Convert.ToString(myRow[7]), 0);
        SubSection.NumberDepth = 0;
        document.Add(Chapter);

        readerList.Add(Reader);

        for (int i = 1; i <= Reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(Reader, i));
        }
        Reader.Close();
    }

    document.Close();

    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=OutPut.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
}
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing different things. Using `Chapter` only makes sense when you create a `Document` from scratch (and using `PdfWriter`). You are using `PdfCopy` to combine existing PDFs. Do these existing PDFs already have bookmarks? This may be a duplicate of [Merge pdfs and add bookmark with iText in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688308/merge-pdfs-and-add-bookmark-with-itext-in-java), but I'm not sure. The question isn't entirely clear/

Comment: I build the bookmarks from scratch; any preexisting bookmark can be overwritten as it won't apply to the logic and nomenclature I want to give. I had stepped on the example you mention but it's not what I need.

Comment: If it's not what you need, you will have to clarify your question. Otherwise people who want to answer won't know what you need.

Comment: Sorry if I do not make my point clear. I'm merging successfully PDF files and build successfully the bookmarks from scratch. BUT they are not grouped as I expected. Imagine all PDF sheets belonging to the same chapter "Chapter1" then I want just a single bookmark entry line with "Chapter1" and a PLUS to open them. What I see now is each line with "Chapter1" and a plus/minus to open/close the underlying section. It feels like being almost there.

Comment: You should start by removing all references to `Chapter` and `Section` from your code. Provide an example where you use `PdfOutline` instead. Rephrase your question with some new example code and show what isn't working for you? There's a `PdfOutline` constructor that takes a `boolean` parameter to define whether or not the bookmark title should be open or closed.