# How to Import Bookmark from xml to existing pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am currently working on pdf projects (dotnet/c#[**Itextsharp pdf**]), I want to export and import bookmarks from one pdf to another pdf (both pdf are having same content, only difference are with bookmark/without bookmark and one is normal pdf and another linked pdf). Exporting bookmarks to xml is working fine but I don`t have the idea of importing exported bookmark(xml) to another pdf. Can any body suggest solution.

Here I am attaching my code.

```
        string inputpdf = "D:\\chapter1.pdf"; string outputbookmark="D:\\chapter1Bookmark.xml";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputpdf);
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        using (StreamWriter Sw = new StreamWriter(outputbookmark))
        {
            SimpleBookmark.ExportToXML(bookmarks, Sw,"ISO8859-1", true);

        }
        reader.Close();
```

My xml output file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<Bookmark>
  <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="1 XYZ 36 806" Action="GoTo" >Introduction</Title>
  <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="1 XYZ 36 410" Action="GoTo" >Getting Started
    <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="1 XYZ 36 364" Action="GoTo" >Printing a test page</Title>
    <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="4 XYZ 36 740" Action="GoTo" >Accessing the novaPDF Printing Preferences &#8211; test the multiline bookmark detection option</Title>
    <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="5 XYZ 36 806" Action="GoTo" >Creating PDF Files</Title>
  </Title>
</Bookmark>
```

My Pdf file available in

```
http://www.novapdf.com/uploads/novapdf_en/media_items/pdf-example-bookmarks.original.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using the [exportToXml()](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.SimpleBookmark#4krn6nbjrbt) method (see also [exportToXml()](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/SimpleBookmark.html#exportToXML-java.util.List-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-boolean-); we currently have the API docs in two different places).

For some reason, you didn't find the [importFromXML()](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/com.itextpdf.text.pdf.SimpleBookmark#3hvs5k6p10g) method (see also [importFromXML()](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/SimpleBookmark.html#importFromXML-java.io.InputStream-)). If you have an XML file containing bookmarks, for instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
<Bookmark>
  <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="1 XYZ 36 806" Action="GoTo" >Introduction</Title>
  <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="1 XYZ 36 410" Action="GoTo" >Getting Started
    <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="1 XYZ 36 364" Action="GoTo" >Printing a test page</Title>
    <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="4 XYZ 36 740" Action="GoTo" >Accessing the novaPDF Printing Preferences &#8211; test the multiline bookmark detection option</Title>
    <Title Color="0 0 0" Page="5 XYZ 36 806" Action="GoTo" >Creating PDF Files</Title>
  </Title>
</Bookmark>
```

You can read this XML file (as an input stream or using a reader), and the `importFromXML()` method will return a `List<HashMap<String,Object>>` object. You can use this object to add the bookmarks to a PDF document using the `setOutlines()` method. See for instance the [BookmarkedTimeTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7#297-bookmarkedtimetable.java) example. Or take a look at the answer to this question: [Merge pdfs and add bookmark with iText in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688308/merge-pdfs-and-add-bookmark-with-itext-in-java)

These examples are (of course) in Java, but if you need the Java version, scroll down on the page that bundles the examples of [chapter 7 of "iText in Action - Second Edition"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-7) and you'll find the C# version of those examples. For instance [BookmarkedTimeTable.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/raw/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/BookmarkedTimeTable.cs)

You'll notice that the method `setOutlines()` doesn't exist in iTextSharp, but that you need to use the property notation:

```
stamper.Outlines = outlines;
```

In this case, `outlines` is an object of type `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` (C#) instead of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`. It should be fairly simple for a C# developer to port the Java examples to C#, but when in doubt, check the `cs` files that are made available on the official web site.

Comment: Thanks man for the your response, I have few clarification on this. Where we use the ImportfromXML?
Is we Pass the importFromXML to outlines? 

      List<Dictionary<string,object>> outlines = 
          new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();
      Dictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      outlines.Add(map);

Comment: Like I am passing my Bookmark xml to Hashmap as follows. HashMap<String, Object> map = SimpleBookmark.ImportFromXMl(Stream); Please guide me if I am wrong.

Comment: So I will go with Second option by Passing XML file stream to hashmap and will back after check.