# iText - How to link bookmark name with specific page number

Tags: java, itext

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\jars\\Test.pdf"));

writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOutlines);

document.open();
document.newPage();
document.add(new Paragraph("ABC"));
PdfOutline root = writer.getRootOutline();
    new PdfOutline(root, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH,1), "ABC", true);

document.newPage();
document.add(new Paragraph("CDE"));
new PdfOutline(root,
                new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH,1),
                "CDE", true);
document.close();
```

What I want is -> On click of ABC bookmark,first page with "ABC" text should open and on click of CDE bookmark,page with "CDE" text should open.

Any help would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge and research is concerned following is the solution.
Did you tried this?

[Tutorial on Adding bookmarks](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/adding-bookmarks-itext-5/)

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF5Fh.jpg)

Go ahead try this solution, let me know if there is any problem.

Following is also good resource.

[Making outline in PDF using IText java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688308/merge-pdfs-and-add-bookmark-with-itext-in-java)